# Re-pointing of the type-structure in fortran

Tags: pointers, fortran

I use the pointers and types in my Fortran code, but still have no sureness that everything is correct. One typical example:

```
program CheckArray

integer :: na = 10, nb=20
integer :: n
type arrtype
  real, pointer :: r1(:) => null()
  real, pointer :: r2(:) => null()
end type
type(arrtype), pointer :: Barr(:) => null()
type(arrtype), pointer :: B       => null()

!-----------

allocate(Barr(1:na))
do n=1,na
  allocate(Barr(n)%r1(-nb:nb),Barr(n)%r2(-nb:nb))
enddo

!----------- from here the lines where I need help

do n=1,na
  B => Barr(n)     ! <- do I need to cleanup B before this operation?
  B%r1(:) = 1
  B%r2(:) = 2
  !...
  CALL checkr(B%r1,B%r2)
  !...
  nullify(B)       ! <- 1) only B nullified, but not Barr(n)? 
                   !    2) do I need this operation?
enddo

end program
```

I cannot find the answer for the following: can I be sure that nullification of the pointer B does not create any changes in the target Barr(:)?

Comment: We can give you some answers about the pointers, but it may help us if you can explain why you are using pointers at all. From the code you show the best advice we can give is not to make you comfortable about the behaviour of the pointers and targets but to say "don't use pointers".

Comment: I agree with @francescalus.  If you can avoid the use of Fortran pointers, then you will avoid a kettle of potential problems.  With the code you show, `B%r2(:) = 2` is undefined as you haven't allocated `Barr(n)%r2(:)`.

Comment: This small program is not the real one. I've written it just to show the logic which I use. Yes, it's forgotten (here) to allocate one array, but let us suppose that this is done.

In reality, the derived types which I use contain many arrays of the different shape. And I use the pointers like B just to reduce the length of the operation. Apart from that, I use this pointer as argument in call of subroutines.

Comment: Pointers are absolutely the wrong tool for every aspect of the logic shown in this question. I think many people who can answer your question here will feel some civic duty not to give ammunition for such dangerous cannon. For example, I'd happily answer the question but, whether it's for you or the next person finding this question on the internet, I'd have to give so much background on how to do this safely, and what the concerns are in generalizing this, that I can't write that answer clearly and concisely.

Comment: For example, if you are using `B=>Barr(n)` just to shorten an expression, then don't: use an ASSOCIATE construct instead. Want component arrays of varying lengths? Make them allocatable instead of pointers. And so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. However, I do not understand what namely is wrong in this logic: a usage of the pointers itself or combination of the derived types and pointers? And which kind of error I have to expect? 
But I understand well that if I use directly Barr(n)%r1 instead of the pointer B%r1, etc, the logic of program remains the same.

Comment: Thanks again for explanation. And I see that that my previous comment is delayed. Okay, I have to think how to use ASSOCIATE.

Comment: Derived types are sufficiently "first class citizens" in modern Fortran that there are few concerns about whether feature X, safe to use with intrinsic types, is good to go with derived types. With `Barr` an intrinsic type, I'd still caution against using pointers. The only difficulty for allocatable components is support for recursion (Fortran 2008 compiler, instead of Fortran 2003) but that's not a concern in your example.

Answer (score 2):

So everything you're doing is *technically* correct, but as you can see from the comments it's going to make a lot of Fortran developers twitchy.

### Specific questions

To answer your specific questions first: in your code section

```
do n=1,na
  B => Barr(n)     ! <- do I need to cleanup B before this operation?
  B%r1(:) = 1
  B%r2(:) = 2
  !...
  CALL checkr(B%r1,B%r2)
  !...
  nullify(B)       ! <- 1) only B nullified, but not Barr(n)? 
                   !    2) do I need this operation?
enddo
```

- you don't "need to cleanup B before this operation". Calling `B => Barr(n)` associates `B` with `Barr(n)`, removing any association `B` had beforehand. The only reason you would need to do "cleanup" was if `B` was responsible for managing some memory (i.e. if it pointed to something that nothing else pointed to). Since you're only using `B` to point at memory managed in other ways, there's no cleanup to do.

1. `nullify(B)` nullifies `B`, and has no effect on `Barr(n)`, correct. It may be worth reading the difference between [nullify](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/a-to-z-reference/m-to-n/nullify.html) and [deallocate](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/a-to-z-reference/c-to-d/deallocate.html). Put simply, `nullify(B)` points `B` at `null()`, and doesn't affect `B`'s previous target, while `deallocate(B)` deallocates `B`'s target (if this is a valid operation), and leaves `B` disassociated.
2. You don't need the `nullify`. The lines `nullify(B)`; `B => Barr(n)` will point `B` at `null()` and then immediately point `B` at `Barr(n)`. This is equivalent to just pointing `B` at `Barr(n)` without the `nullify`.

### Why pointers are discouraged

Historically, Fortran's party piece on the performance front was that it [assumed](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.6/g77/Aliasing-Assumed-To-Work.html) its variables weren't [aliased](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)). This means that if you're working with a variable you assume that the contents of that variable won't change unless you explicitly change them. Making this assumption allows an optimising compiler to make a bunch of optimisations which wouldn't be possible otherwise.

In modern fortran, there are (at least) two ways of causing variables to be aliased. The first is passing the same variable (or parts of that variable) to two different arguments of the same procedure, and the second is by using pointers. In your code, you are aliasing `Barr(n)` by pointing `B` at it.

In the best case, the compiler will know that you're aliasing a variable, and the worst that will happen is that you might miss out on some optimisations. In the worst case, however, the compiler won't know that you're aliasing a variable, and will make optimisations that assume no aliasing. This can very easily break your code, in hard-to-notice, hard-to-debug kinds of ways. In order to understand which of the two cases you'll be dealing with, you need to understand in detail how Fortran thinks about aliasing. It's much easier to just avoid aliasing altogether.

### A better approach

Instead of using pointers to store arrays of variable size, consider using [allocatable](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/xl-fortran-aix/16.1.0?topic=attributes-allocatable-fortran-2003) arrays. For example, your code section

```
integer :: na = 10, nb=20
integer :: n
type arrtype
  real, pointer :: r1(:) => null()
  real, pointer :: r2(:) => null()
end type
type(arrtype), pointer :: Barr(:) => null()

allocate(Barr(1:na))
do n=1,na
  allocate(Barr(n)%r1(-nb:nb), Barr(n)%r2(-nb:nb))
enddo
```

would become

```
integer :: na = 10, nb=20
integer :: n
type arrtype
  real, allocatable :: r1(:)
  real, allocatable :: r2(:)
end type
type(arrtype), allocatable :: Barr(:)

allocate(Barr(1:na))
do n=1,na
  allocate(Barr(n)%r1(-nb:nb), Barr(n)%r2(-nb:nb))
enddo
```

Then, instead of using pointers to refer to specific bits of variables, consider just using the variables directly, or using [associate](https://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/associate) if the variables are too verbose. For example, your code section

```
do n=1,na
  B => Barr(n)     ! <- do I need to cleanup B before this operation?
  B%r1(:) = 1
  B%r2(:) = 2
  !...
  CALL checkr(B%r1,B%r2)
  !...
  nullify(B)       ! <- 1) only B nullified, but not Barr(n)? 
                   !    2) do I need this operation?
enddo
```

would become

```
do n=1,na
  associate(B => Barr(n))
    B%r1(:) = 1
    B%r2(:) = 2
    !...
    CALL checkr(B%r1,B%r2)
    !...
  end associate
enddo
```

Note that `B` here is not a pointer, and you should not declare `B` before the `associate` statement. From the compiler's point of view, `B` is simply another way of accessing `Barr(n)`. The relevant section of the [Fortran 2018 draft standard](https://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fortran+2018) is section 19.5.1.6:

> [...] Execution of an ASSOCIATE [...] statement
> establishes an association between each `selector` and the corresponding `associate name` of the construct.
>
> [...]
>
> Each associate name remains associated with the corresponding selector throughout the execution of the executed
> block. Within the block, each selector is known by and may be accessed by the corresponding associate name.
> On completion of execution of the construct, the association is terminated.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm very grateful for very detailed instruction.
And the last question (I did not find the answer in tutorials): do I need to declare B as the pointer before association? 
Like that: type(arrtype), pointer :: B

Comment: Thank you again for very instructive explanation.